# env variables are not accessible in nextjs 11.1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I"m using nextjs 11.1 and I have 2 files `env.development` and `.env.production`. Below are the contents they have.

```
.env.development
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:3000/api/
```

And

```
.env.production
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT=https://production.com/api/
```

Inside my index.tsx I am trying to access these variables but .env is empty.

```
const Home = () => {
    console.log('process.env: ', process.env); // this returns empty object {}.

  return (
    <>
        HOME
    </>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

Where am I making mistake and how can I access these variables?

Comment: Use .env.local Here is the doc https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables

Comment: @J.dev if you scroll further down on that link page you'll see that I should also be able to use `.env.development` and `.env.production`.

Comment: Why are you trying to log `process.env`? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: @Phil to see if it has `NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT` variable and I have access to it.

Comment: Sounds like premature debugging which seems to be the source of at least 50% of [tag:javascript] questions on StackOverflow and close to 100% if you narrow that down to `console.log()`